# how can i make the values im reading into a dictionary not be in tuple form or list

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

```
def read(fname):
    data=dict()
    with open(fname,'r') as file:
        for line in file:
            r = line.strip().split(',')
            print(r)
            data[r[0]]=r[1],r[2],r[3],r[4],r[5]


        print(data)
        return data
```

I want it to be like {key: 1,2,3,4} not {key:(1,2,3,4)}.
this is what I have so far

Comment: You'll need a different programming language.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `join()` to make a comma-separated string.

```
data[r[0]] = ','.join(r[1:6])
```

Comment: sorry but this makes it all into 1 value in the dictionary I want each number as its own value

Comment: That's not a valid dictionary. Each key in a dictionary just gets one value.